# Qt Mac OS X "Grab", getting focus, simulate mouse click

Tags: c++, macos, qt, mouse, simulate

I have a Qt app running on Mac OS X. Got problem with the preloaded app "Grab". My app takes the full screen, when it's switched from other app by Command+Tab, there is no other window on top of it. But have exception with "Grab": if I launch Grab, go to menu Capture/Select, Grab's float window shows up, when I use Command+Tab to switch to my app, Grab is on top of my full screen window. I did following in my app in order to turn down the float window:

call setWindowState(Qt::WindowActive) in paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pEvent) only once, this make my window gets focus, tested, focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e) was called.

But Grab is still there. I found a mouse click on my window turns off Grab's float win, so I tried to simulate a mouse click when my win is stable, using something like:

```
QPoint pos( 1, 1 );
QWidget *w = this; //qApp->widgetAt(mapToGlobal(pos));
QMouseEvent *press = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(w, press);
QMouseEvent *release = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(w, release);
```

mousePressEvent() and mousePressRelease() are trigger so it's successful. But not affecting the Grab window.

Call show(), raise(), activateWindow() on all topLevelWidgets() doesn't work either.

My widget is derived from QScrollArea, -> QAbstractScrollArea, -> QFrame, -> QWidget

My widget is launched from a thread, the thread is from QMainWindow.

So my questions are:
1. is there any way to REALLY simulate the mouse click, which means I can see mouse click on screen?
2. any other way to kill the Grab win?

Thanks